# List to Appear in Map

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, material-ui

I'm working on the list part of my map.  The issue is, it's not being displayed on the Sidebar when I run it.  I need some help as to what I need to add into my List code to make it appear. Full code can be found [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/73l3j8m6j).

```
          <List>
            {this.props.venues &&
              this.props.venues.map((venue, index) => (
                <ListItem key={index}>
                  <ListItemText primary={venue.name} />
                </ListItem>
              ))}
          </List>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `venue` inside braces. (or you have to do `primary={venue.venue.name}`)

```
         <List>
            {this.props.venues &&
              this.props.venues.map(({venue}, index) => (
                <ListItem key={index}>
                  <ListItemText primary={venue.name} />
                </ListItem>
              ))}
          </List>
```